# Implement an icon in google maps that rotates based on heading on polyline

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am working on a project where i need to track the elephant movement. I have done the example [Animate Symbols](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-symbol-animate) in samples. But i need to replace the circle with an elephant icon and that icon needs to rotate based on the heading. A perfect example for what i am doing is [Flight Radar Application](http://www.flightradar24.com/8.73,79.37/7)

Thanks

Comment: Create and use elephant-symbol, the symbol will rotate automatically.

Comment: Sorry i am new to google-maps. Could you tell me how to create an elephant symbol?

Comment: You must draw it by using a program that is able to export graphics as SVG(e.g. inkscape) and the use the path for that image, extracted from the SVG.

Comment: I did what you said but image is not rendering. Extracted path isn't working. Example path : d="M104.929,585.5c-1-203,17-152,81-146c-9.259,44.444-3,140.126-3,150c-2,2,49,1,69,0
  c0,0-14.624-86.984,17.071-110.5c31-23,158.038-20.271,192-5c27.188,12.225,12.929,115.5,12.929,115.5s0,0,67,0
  c39-387-155-361-205-354.002c-87-61.002-144-26.998-163,0.002c-103-1-107,345-107,345L104.929,585.5z".

Comment: Demo(including a path based on http://4vector.com/free-vector/elephant-silhouet-clip-art-118735):  http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/8hzmS/